# Unlist a list of list in python

Tags: python

I have a list of list like [[a], [b], [c]]. How do I make it: [a, b, c] efficently?

Comment: That's called "flattening" a list, for future reference.

Comment: l = [["a"], ["b"], ["c"]]
     flat_list = [item for sublist in l for item in sublist]
     print (flat_list)